# Facebook Accesstoken Issues

Tags: facebook-access-token

I am new to coding and i would like to clarify the following question:
Has Facebook blocked all accesstokens from the developer page from reading and extracting FB user profile ID?

Comment: you get access to user data with a user token. not sure what you are talking about?

Comment: I am using a python program to extract out individuals Facebook name and their user id and the output file will be written onto an excel sheet. But in order for you to access the Facebook, you require a accesstoken right? That's why was wondering if that accesstoken's privilege is blocked by Facebook or not

Comment: what exactly do you think is "blocked" and what have you tried so far? there is no "privilege", there are just some different access tokens and different ways to generate them.

Comment: btw, you cannot get ANY data of users without their authorization. no name, no id, nothing.

Comment: okay what i am trying to do is using the python code, i would like to automate to search user name and ID based on their phone numbers. Because if i were to manually key in a phone number in the Facebook search bar, it will either show a result or no match. Thus, i would like to automate this process using large sets of phone numbers. Am i able to do so? and do i need a different type of accesstokens?

Comment: there is no api for that. you cannot search for users by phone number. you cannot even get the phone number of a user if he authorizes your app. phone numbers are off limits. what you can do with facebook search is not always available with their api.

Comment: Ahh okay. Because the programmer did a python code which he said can extract and write the profile name and profile id based on the phone numbers but then the code was only able to do that for Page name and page id but not for profile. Apparently the programmer was using Facebook Graph API to do the search. So is this method even possible or you require different types of accesstokens or privileges to do it?

Comment: again, there is NO way to do what you want to achieve. at least not for user profiles. if you want to know about different access tokens, why not just take a look at the docs first? this is a platform for developers, we require everyone to do some research and testing before asking questions ;) here is the link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Alright, will check on the link. Thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they have blocked the token access, but i am not sure about reading, extracting FB user profile ID